# Sending Duplicate Emails from GridView

Tags: asp.net, webforms

The purpose of this code is to send emails in the `GridView` to individuals whose email listed in there, so the code works fine but it does something weird.  Let me explain it here, so if my `GridView` looks like this

```
ID            Name              Email
4             Mike              Mike@.com
6             John              John@.com
9             David             David@.com
```

Once I hit the send button,

1. Mike receives all 3 different emails with all the 3 ID’s in the URL starting ID4, ID6, ID9 in the mail message body.
2. John receives only a 2 emails starting ID6 and ID9
3. David receives only 1 email which is the email for ID9 in mail message body.

What am I doing wrong here?  I need each one to receive their respective email only.  Can someone help?  Note, the `DateKeyName` in the `GridView` is “Assigned_To” so I am not sure if I need to change that into `“ID”`.  If I do that then It will throw an error.  thanks
Here is the code:

```
protected void btnSendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("chkItem");
            if (cb.Checked)
            {

                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(GridView1.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex]["Assigned_To"].ToString()));
                mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fromEmailAddress"]);
                mailMessage.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
                //Text/HTML
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
                string mySubURI = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString().Replace("Test.aspx", "ABC.aspx");
                mySubURI += String.Format("&ID={0}", gr.Cells[0].Text);
                mailMessage.Body = "this is just test... " + " " + Environment.NewLine + mySubURI;
                mailMessage.Subject = "Test";


                System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                try
                {
                    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

                    //Response.Write("<B>Email Has been sent successfully.</B>");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.Message);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you reformat your representation of the grid?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how it should look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a new MailMessage after you check the checkbox, what you're doing now is reusing the same message for each iteration and adding a new mail address without clearing the previous ones.

```
protected void btnSendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("chkItem");
        if (cb.Checked)
        {
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(GridView1.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex]["Assigned_To"].ToString()));
            mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fromEmailAddress"]);
            mailMessage.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
            //Text/HTML
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
            string mySubURI = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString().Replace("Test.aspx", "ABC.aspx");
            mySubURI += String.Format("&ID={0}", gr.Cells[0].Text);
            mailMessage.Body = "this is just test... " + " " + Environment.NewLine + mySubURI;
            mailMessage.Subject = "Test";


            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            try
            {
                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

                //Response.Write("<B>Email Has been sent successfully.</B>");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this:  you're creating the mail message once, but re-using it for every row.  So for every grid row you add a new To entry ... but you've still got the old ones!